# Looping functionality in Powershell for each folder inside System.DefaultWorkingDirectory

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Below is my PowerShell Script which creates a zip file of my DefaultWorkingDirectory in Azure DevOps and Upload it in SharePoint successfully for my end users to Download. I would like to create a loop for my directory and upload each folder in SharePoint and create a separate link for each folder rather than just parent directory which I doing now... Would like some help in creating this for-each functionality in PowerShell:

Here is my existing code:

```
    Function UPLOAD-FILE
{
    param($workingDir, $tempDir, $clientId, $clientSecret, $artifactname)
    CREATE-ARCHIVE -workingDir $workingDir -tempDir $tempDir    
    Write-Host $workingDir    
    write-host "$SPid"
    write-host "$LibId"
    $file = $workingDir + "\" +$tempDir + "\" + "$($artifactname).zip"
    $fileSize = (Get-Item $file).length
    $uploadURLObject = GET-UPLOADLINK -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret -artifactname $artifactname
    $tokenObject = GET-TOKEN -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret
    $uploadHeaders = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Range", "bytes " + 0 +"-" + ($fileSize-1) + "/" + $fileSize)
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Length", $fileSize)
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+ $tokenObject.access_token)    
    $uploadBody = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $uploadURLObject.uploadUrl -Method 'PUT' -Headers $uploadHeaders -Body $uploadBody
    $response | ConvertTo-Json
    REMOVE-TEMPDIR -workingDir $workingDirectory -tempDir $tempDirectory
    return $response
    
}

Function GET-UPLOADLINK
{
    param($clientId, $clientSecret, $artifactname)
    $tokenObject = GET-TOKEN -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret
    $uploadLinkRequestHeaders = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $uploadLinkRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    $uploadLinkRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+ $tokenObject.access_token)
    $uploadLinkRequestBody = ""     
    #update the actual link  
    $fullname = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$($SPid)/drives/$($LibId)/root/children/"    
    $comname = $fullname + $artifactname   
    $uploadLinkResponse = Invoke-RestMethod "$($comname).zip/createUploadSession" -Method 'POST' -Headers $uploadLinkRequestHeaders -Body $uploadLinkRequestBody
    $uploadLinkResponse | ConvertTo-Json
    return $uploadLinkResponse    
}

Function CREATE-ARCHIVE
{
    param($workingDir, $tempDir)
    write-host $workingDir
    cd $workingDir
    md $tempDir
    Compress-Archive -Path $workingDir -DestinationPath $workingDir\$tempDir\$artifactname
}

Function REMOVE-TEMPDIR
{
    param($workingDir, $tempDir)
    #This will be the last step
    rm $workingDir\$tempDir -Recurse   
}



UPLOAD-FILE -workingDir $workingDirectory -tempDir $tempDirectory -clientId $CLIENT_ID -clientSecret $CLIENT_SECRET -artifactname $artifactname
```

Here my $workingDirectory is  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) defined as argument in powershell task called in release pipeline $tempDir is "temp" and  $artifactname is a custom name just to identify my directory. Rest variables are self explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `ls` command or `Get-ChildItem` commands to get the child folders under folder `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` See below example:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
#or using ls command
#$items  = ls $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

foreach($item in $items){
   $name = $item.Name
   $fullName = $item.FullName
   #if the path is a folder. Then create a zip
   if(Test-Path -Path $fullName -PathType Container){
      Compress-Archive -Path $fullName -DestinationPath "$name.zip"
     }
}
```